# How to debug Yii PHP code in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, xdebug

I have set-up my WAMP installation to debug a PHP website in NetBeans.

This works fine (up to a point, hence this question) and I can single-step through the PHP code, and watch variables, etc.

However, some bits of the code - those provided within the Yii framework - are throwing exceptions, but attempts to single-step through this code fail - the debugger leaps over portions of the code and I can't observe what's going on.

The debugger lands on a call to `HandleError`, but I can't see how it got there. The displayed Call Stack isn't showing all the steps taken to get where it is.

I've seen lots of comments on the web about this, but haven't yet seen an answer on how to enable this framework's code to be debugged on my PC.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: What if you add the yii files at the root of your netbean project?